# NSBatchInsertRequest not updating content in some cases when perform

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsbatchupdaterequest

I'm facing a strange behaviour with `NSBatchInsertRequest` and I don't seems to understand what is causing my problem.
I have some piece of code that updates local data depending on some remote data changes.
The model that is being updated contains a boolean `shared` indicating if the item is shared or not. Updating this model seems to work correctly when the boolean goes from `false` to `true` but when trying to update the data with the reverse action the new local data doesn't seem to be persisted and I end up having the `shared` variable always returning `true` even is the content of the `NSBatchInsertRequest` has it set as `false`.

Following are the different parts of my logic and my managed object description.

[image]

**Helper functions**

```swift
   func newTaskContext(type: TaskContextType,
                        transactionAuthor: String = #function) -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let taskContext = container.newBackgroundContext()
        taskContext.name = type.rawValue
        taskContext.transactionAuthor = transactionAuthor
        taskContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        taskContext.undoManager = nil
        return taskContext
    }

    func newBatchInsertRequest<T>(entity: NSEntityDescription,
                                  sourceItems: [T],
                                  hydrateBlock: @escaping (NSManagedObject, T) -> Void)
        -> NSBatchInsertRequest {
        var index = 0
        let request = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: entity,
                                           managedObjectHandler: { object in
                                               guard index < sourceItems.count else { return true }
                                               let item = sourceItems[index]
                                               hydrateBlock(object, item)
                                               index += 1
                                               return false
                                           })
        return request
    }

extension ShareEntity {
    func hydrate(from symmetricallyEncryptedShare: SymmetricallyEncryptedShare, userId: String) {
        let share = symmetricallyEncryptedShare.share
        content = share.content
        contentFormatVersion = share.contentFormatVersion ?? -1
        contentKeyRotation = share.contentKeyRotation ?? -1
        createTime = share.createTime
        expireTime = share.expireTime ?? -1
        owner = share.owner
        permission = share.permission
        primary = share.primary
        shareID = share.shareID
        symmetricallyEncryptedContent = symmetricallyEncryptedShare.encryptedContent
        targetID = share.targetID
        targetType = share.targetType
        vaultID = share.vaultID
        addressID = share.addressID
        userID = userId
        shareRoleID = share.shareRoleID
        targetMembers = share.targetMembers
        shared = share.shared
    }
}

    func execute(batchInsertRequest request: NSBatchInsertRequest,
                 context: NSManagedObjectContext) async throws {
        try await context.perform {
            guard context.hasPersistentStore else { return }
            let fetchResult = try context.execute(request)
            if let result = fetchResult as? NSBatchInsertResult,
               let success = result.result as? Bool, success {
                return
            } else {
                throw error
            }
        }
    }
```

**Main local data updating entry point**

```swift
   func upsertShares(_ shares: [SymmetricallyEncryptedShare], userId: String) async throws {
        let taskContext = newTaskContext(type: .insert)

        let batchInsertRequest =
            newBatchInsertRequest(entity: ShareEntity.entity(context: taskContext),
                                  sourceItems: shares) { managedObject, share in
                (managedObject as? ShareEntity)?.hydrate(from: share, userId: userId)
            }

        try await execute(batchInsertRequest: batchInsertRequest, context: taskContext)
    }
```

I don't understand why the update of `ShareEntity` work one way but cannot be updated back to containing the variable `shared` as false.
Any tips or advice would be welcome on this issue.